# client->soapFunction(); and soapCall not returning data but getLastResponse does

Tags: php, soap

The code below correctly returns the XML from the soap sever that I'm accessing. If I echo $client->Function(); however it returns Object id #2.

```
$client=new SoapClient("http://blackbird.integrated.local/PricingTool/WebService.asmx?WSDL",
  array('trace' => true));

//echo $client->__soapCall('TestSOAP', array('YesNo' => '1'));
$client->GetDAAAvailablility(array('PartNo' => '100C'));

echo $client->__getLastResponse();
```

I'm wondering why this is, and to correctly call the soap functions incase I'm doing something incorrectly.

Comment: have you tried doing var_dump() or print_r() on the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was part of a bug in an older version of PHP, updating to the latest version made the request work as expected.